# Dynamically Adding and removing context handler from Jetty Server

Tags: jetty, application-server

Is there any way to dynamically add or remove context handlers from Jetty Application Server ?

Comment: Please provide more information. Which version of Jetty. How are you running the server? What exactly do you mean by "dynamically" ?  The simple answer to your question is "yes". The more useful answer will require a more detailed question.

Comment: @Tim: While server is running, i want to add a new Handler class which i can do, but i want to add a new context handler associated with the handler class. I was searching for the way how i can accomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the deployer mechanism hot deploys contexts to jetty:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/ContextDeployer

Answer (score 0):

For Jetty 9/10/11:

As a supplement to [Jetty 9 (embedded): Adding handlers during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043097/jetty-9-embedded-adding-handlers-during-runtime)

```java
    public void run() throws Exception {

        ...

        System.out.println("Press enter to remove context handler for /hello2");
        System.in.read();

        // important! stop context explicitly.
        contextHandler2.stop();
        // remove handler
        contextHandlerCollection.removeHandler(contextHandler2);

        System.out.println("Press enter to exit.");
        System.in.read();

        server.stop();

        System.out.println("stopped");
   }
```