# Jetty 9 (embedded): Adding handlers during runtime

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Is there any way to add handlers to a running embedded Jetty instance? We have migrated an old Jetty 6 based project to Jetty 9 and we need for our plugin system the possibility add and remove dynamically handlers...

See the example below...

```java
Server server = new Server();
[...]
server.start();
[...]
Handler[] existingHandler = server.getHandlers();

// There is no more
server.addHandler(newHandler);

// only this you can do, but only if the server is stopped
server.setHandler(newHandler)
```

Note: `newHandler` is a `HandlerCollection`...

Comment: Do you have, or use, anything in your handlers that are subject to the Jetty [LifeCycle](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/LifeCycle.html) (that all Jetty Handlers are part of)?

Comment: Of course, they are part...

The Problem is jetty server setHandler Method, they throw new IllegalStateException("STARTED") if the server is started. Maybe for a good reason so I do not know how to handle this. I know there is a DeplomentManager, but I found no extended example. Those on jetty documentation show only how to handle one resource context with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Jetty 9.1.0.v20131115 you can use the [`mutableWhenRunning`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection.html#HandlerCollection%28boolean%29) flag on `HandlerCollection` constructor ...

```
HandlerCollection coll = new HandlerCollection(true);
```

This will ignore the `isStarted()` tests on the collection itself during [`.setHandlers(Handlers[])`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection.java#L81-L82) and [`.addHandler(Handler)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/HandlerCollection.java#L155) calls.

This behavior is only available for the `HandlerCollection` itself, you can add individual handlers, or set the entire handler tree without regards to the `LifeCycle` of the `HandlerCollection`.

Eg:

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);
HandlerCollection myhandlers = new HandlerCollection(true);
server.setHandler(myhandlers);

// add some initial handlers
myhandlers.setHandlers(new Handlers[] { helloHandler, indexHandler });

// start server
server.start();

// ... at some point later, during runtime
FooHandler fooHandler = new FooHandler();
fooHandler.start();
myhandlers.addHandler(fooHandler);

BarHandler barHandler = new BarHandler();
barHandler.start();
myhandlers.addHandler(barHandler);
```

Comment: Sorry to say the flag is already set, but setHandler of the server object does not care about. Only my used handler collection cares about it and I can add new ones. But the added handler / contexts seem not to be deployed? How to handle this in Jetty 9? In Jetty 6 we just call addHandler on the server...

Comment: OK updating to 9.1 does work, now my contexts are available / can be added during runtime!

Comment: Please tell how you did it! Otherwise your comment is useless.

Comment: @JensPeters updating to 9.1 also doesn't work for me, could you please tell how you did it

Comment: @Uday might make sense to ask a new question on why this answer isn't working for you (supply your code an any errors/stacktraces you see)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt now my problem is fixed, i have started context explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

Here a complete code sample. Next to using `HandlerCollection(true)`, it is also important to start the new context handler explicitly.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;

public class DynamicContextHandlers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new DynamicContextHandlers().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler();
        contextHandler.setContextPath("/hello");
        contextHandler.setResourceBase(".");
        contextHandler.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        contextHandler.setHandler(new HelloHandler(""));

        HandlerCollection contextHandlerCollection = new HandlerCollection(true); // important! use parameter
                                                                                    // mutableWhenRunning==true

        // add context handler before starting server (started implicitly)
        contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(contextHandler);
        server.setHandler(contextHandlerCollection);

        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started at port " + port + " with context handler for /hello");

        System.out.println("Press enter to add context handler for /hello2");
        System.in.read();

        ContextHandler contextHandler2 = new ContextHandler();
        contextHandler2.setContextPath("/hello2");
        contextHandler2.setResourceBase(".");
        contextHandler2.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        contextHandler2.setHandler(new HelloHandler("2"));

        // add handler after starting server.
        contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(contextHandler2);
        // important! start context explicitly.
        contextHandler2.start();

        System.out.println("Press enter to exit.");
        System.in.read();

        server.stop();

    }

    public class HelloHandler extends AbstractHandler {
        String string;

        public HelloHandler(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World" + string + "</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```